# csv file -> SQLite table, and show listview

Tags: android, sqlite, csv, assets, readline

I want convert '*.csv' file(in android assets folder) to SQLite table.

then, show table using listview.
(: read csv -using-> sqlite table -using-> show listview)

but there was all error.

please help.

- sorry for my unclear english.
- I don't have any rooting device. always running in my real device(not test device or virtual machine).

still error in code. and 'test.db' file is not created.

logcat : Nullpointerexception, Can't open file for reading, ...etc.

---

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
    public static DBHelper mDBManager;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    Cursor c;
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    String arrname[] = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mtname);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.first);

        mDBManager = new DBHelper(this);  
        db = mDBManager.getWritableDatabase();
        db = mDBManager.getReadableDatabase();

        Log.d("FirstActivity:onCreate", "oncreate");
        displayList();
    }

    private void displayList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        c = mDBManager.SortAllRows();
        Log.d("FirstActivity:displayList", "displayList");
        int i = 0;
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {        
            do {
                arrname[i] = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_name"));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        c.close();
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.first, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH = "/mnt/sdcard/";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "test";
    private DBHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;
    private String fileName = "test.csv"; // "file:///android_asset/test.csv"; //"/mnt/sdcard/test.csv";

    private Context mcontext;

    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_PATH + "test.db", null, 1);
        mcontext = context;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(_index INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, _name TEXT, _ad TEXT, _ca TEXT, _sp TEXT);");

        AssetManager am = mcontext.getAssets();
        InputStream is = null;

        try {
            is = am.open(fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("DBHelper:onCreate", "csv file open");
        }

        BufferedReader buffer = null;
        buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));


/** I tried this way. but there was all error(Including the above way). NullPointerException **
* for '*. csv' file to change the table of sqlite. (csv file->sqlite table)
        //InputStream in = mcontext.getAssets().open(fileName);
        //BufferReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"));

        //AssetManager am = mcontext.getAssets();
        //BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(am.open(fileName), "UTF-8"));

        //FileReader fr = new FileReader(new File("file:///android_asset/","test.csv"));
        //BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(fr);

        //AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = am.openFd(fileName);
        //FileReader file = new FileReader(descriptor.getFileDescriptor());

        //FileReader file = new FileReader(fileName);
        //BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(file);
*/

        String line = "";
        String columns = "_index, _name, _ad, _ca, _sp";
        String str1 = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + columns + ") values(";
        String str2 = ");";

        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            while ((line = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str1);
                String[] str = line.split(",");
                sb.append("'" + str[0] + "',");
                sb.append(str[1] + "',");
                sb.append(str[2] + "',");
                sb.append(str[3] + "'");
                sb.append(str[4] + "'");
                sb.append(str2);
                db.execSQL(sb.toString());
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();

        Log.d("DBHelper:onCreate","DB CREATE");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w("DBHelper:onUpgrade", "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public Cursor SortAllRows() {
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "_index", "_name", "_ad", "_ca", "_sp" }, null, null, null, null, null, "_name" + " ASC");
    }

    public void close() {
        Log.d("DBHelper:close","DBhelper close");
        if (dbHelper != null) {
            dbHelper.close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
11-27 15:13:15.893: E/(19898): Can't open file for reading
11-27 15:13:15.893: E/(19898): Can't open file for reading
11-27 15:13:15.973: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4c3ab000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:78
11-27 15:13:16.024: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(19898): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
11-27 15:13:16.024: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4c728000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:81
11-27 15:13:16.024: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4be87000 size:1536000
11-27 15:13:16.024: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4c3ab000 size:1536000
11-27 15:13:16.034: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4be87000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:74
11-27 15:13:16.704: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4c3ab000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:78
11-27 15:13:18.606: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(19898): <ConfigWindowMatch:2081>: Format RGBA_8888.
11-27 15:13:18.606: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4c89f000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:87
11-27 15:13:18.636: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4ca16000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:90
11-27 15:13:18.646: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4c728000 size:1536000
11-27 15:13:18.646: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4be87000 size:1536000
11-27 15:13:18.646: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Unmapping buffer  base:0x4c3ab000 size:1536000
11-27 15:13:19.837: D/memalloc(19898): ion: Mapped buffer base:0x4be87000 size:1536000 offset:0 fd:74
11-27 15:13:29.196: D/FirstActivity:onCreate(19898): mDBManager
11-27 15:13:29.196: D/FirstActivity:onCreate(19898): oncreate
11-27 15:13:29.196: I/FirstActivity:displayList(19898): displayList
11-27 15:13:29.196: W/dalvikvm(19898): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40ce31f8)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.FirstActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1961)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1986)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1152)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4449)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at com.example.test.DBHelper.SortAllRows(DBHelper.java:139)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at com.example.test.FirstActivity.displayList(FirstActivity.java:50)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at com.example.test.FirstActivity.onCreate(FirstActivity.java:38)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1925)
11-27 15:13:29.196: E/AndroidRuntime(19898):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize `db` variable in your constructor. So:

`SortAllRows()` method throws `NullPointerException` when executing `return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "_index", "_name", "_ad", "_ca", "_sp" }, null, null, null, null, null, "_name" + " ASC");`

Also, your table name will be `test` not `test.db` since `private static final String TABLE_NAME = "test";`

Answer (score 0):

why don't you include that *.csv file into the SQlite database and then add that database to the assets folder. This will make things easy and you can then easily fetch the details from the database.